# Multiple Users iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm working on an iOS app that will be used by multiple users. For example, this will be installed at a kiosk, so multiple people will interact with it and then be able to login to Facebook and share content.

I'm able to login/logout with Facebook credentials in the application; however, when I go to login the next time... the embedded popup safari browser remembers the previous logged in user and says "You have already authorized ". What's proper way to clear the user, so that the safari browser does not remember the last user? I have searched everywhere and people suggest clearing cookies with var httpCookie:NSHTTPCookieStorage=NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()... but this returns 0 items. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: How are you asking users to log in? Will the application open Safari to login? Or is the login handled in-app?

Comment: With the new Facebook iOS SDK, it defaults to a Safari View Controller. So, when you click the login button... it's a trimmed down version of Safari, but shares all of the cookies... so if the user is already logged in, then you are immediately prompted to grant access to app. If not, then you login and then you are prompted to grant access to the app.

So, its really opening Safari and it remembers your login credentials and I don't know how to clear this from my app.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    for cookie in storage.cookies! {
        storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
}
```

Comment: This returns 0 items... <NSHTTPCookieStorage cookies count:0>. I put this code in viewDidLoad right before it creates the Facebook login button in the view.

Comment: Did you try using:

    FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()

Comment: Yes, and I also tried setting the access token and current profile to nil. Here is my logout method that gets called when I click logout...

`func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

        print("User Logged Out")
        
        FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil)
        FBSDKProfile.setCurrentProfile(nil)
        FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
        
        let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
        for cookie in storage.cookies! {
            storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }

    }`

Comment: Can you try printing the values after you reset them? So after FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil) do a print for the currentAccessToken to see if it's really nil.

Comment: Ok... here is logout function now...

`if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil) {
            print("Access Token is NIL")
        }
        else {
            print("Access Token is NOT NIL")
        }`
 
Console ouput... 
Access Token is NIL

Comment: okay and if you try something like print(FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()) you need to try printing everything you do to see what's going wrong.

Comment: My understanding is the logout method is just a void method, so it doesn't return anything to print. From the docs it says it sets the current access token and current profile to nil. I've verified this by outputting those two things to the console and they show nil. 

`NSLog("Current Access Token: %@", String(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()))
        NSLog("Current Profile: %@", String(FBSDKProfile.currentProfile()))`

2016-07-20 15:54:17.369 BoothApp[2384:882251] Current Access Token: nil
2016-07-20 15:54:17.369 BoothApp[2384:882251] Current Profile: nil